# function that returns a select with options, using React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a JSON of courthouse that contains one `id` and one `name`. The JSON contains an unlimited number of courthouses. I need to create a `<Select>` full of `<Option>`. the `<Option>` value will be the id, and the `<Option>` content will be the name.

So i got this function

```
createSelectCourtHouse:function(){
    return ( 
    <Form.Field className='form-control' type='select' name='request.courthouse_id' id='accused_lastname' placeholder="Nom de l'accusé" id='accused_lastname' onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'accused_lastname')}>
       this.state.courthouseData.forEach(function(courthouse) {
           return (
               <option value={courthouse.i}>{courthouse.name}</option>
           );
       })
    </Form.Field>)
},
```

but it seems like i can't do a forEach inside a return. So i tried this way :

```
var field = ( 
      <Form.Field className='form-control' type='select' name='request.courthouse_id' id='accused_lastname' placeholder="Nom de l'accusé" id='accused_lastname' onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'accused_lastname')}>
         this.state.courthouseData.forEach(function(courthouse) {
              <option value={courthouse.id}>{courthouse.name}</option>
          });
      </Form.Field>
    )
return field;
```

But it doesnt work.  I feel like im close to getting the answer but simply cant get the hand on it. Any ideas ?

TL;DR : I need to create a select with option filled with value from a JSON.

Comment: forEach doesn't return anything, you probably want to use reduce

Comment: or more likely `map`

Comment: could you be less specific ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` to create jsx elements. Try:

```
var options = this.state.courthouseData.map(function(courthouse) {
   return (
     <option value={courthouse.i}>{courthouse.name}</option>
   );
});
```

I'm not sure where this function is being called but, chances are you want to return the output in your render function:

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <SomeParentElement>
      {options}
    </SomeParentElement>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want to read [Why Select Value?](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#why-select-value) in the docs

It's not clear to me why you've created `Form.Field` abstraction when the `select` element is perfectly find for expressing your needs

```
<select className="form-control" name="request.courthouse_id">
  {this.state.courthouseData.map((courthouse, i) => (
    <option key={i} value={courthouse.id}>{courthouse.name}</option>
  ))}
</select>
```

This has the added benefit of being able to pass a `value` prop to the `select` element that will properly display the default/chosen `option`.

Comment: Because i'm using the React formal librairie, it eases the further validations.

Comment: Nevertheless, the `courthouseData.map` syntax should help you out